# What is the maximum number of inputs to a logic gate that is being used in computing hardware these days?

Tags: digital-logic, cmos, boolean-algebra, programmable-logic

I was referring to this [question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/538996/260943), but I had a confusion due to the concept of programmable logic devices. Image from [UW](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse370/99au/lectures/au99-05/au99-05.pdf) page 7. Here the OR section can have up to 8 inputs to it. I'm confused about how the PL hardware avoids the transistor level problems while having so many inputs to a gate.

[image: PLA]

Comment: A "gate" is an abstraction. You can implement an OR gate with 1000 inputs out of <lazy to calculate number> 2-input OR gates.

Comment: Right, but those subsequent stages of logic (might) increase the delay, which is not a good news.

Comment: OR is a parallel operation

Comment: This is a separate question. If you want to ask how to implement a many-input OR gate in  a way that will not affect the delay - ask it.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 On the transistor level - yes. Not if implementing with other OR gates, it will require an `log N` deep tree.

Comment: Correct.........

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75, making the OR gate wider increases the propagation delays through all of it towards its single output. Plus increased routing delays from what's feeding it.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: It takes 999 2-input gates to handle 1000 inputs. It doesn't matter how you structure them.

Comment: @DaveTweed You can always do more though :)

Answer (score 2):

Standard cell libraries tend to limit the number gate inputs to 4. More than that increases delay, and doesn’t fit well on the cell placement grid.

What you show is a higher-level macro called a Programmable Logic Array, or PLA, which can implement wider input functions.

Comment: As I don't know the internal structure of the PLA here, how do they support wider input functions and if they use the n-stage cascading of OR gates, how do they reduce the delay? FPGA although structurally different, is used for low latency applications, right? Don't have the exact value for low latency, but gate stages aren't good for low latency, right?

Comment: PLAs support a generalized ‘sum of products’ form using shared wiring to implement wide AND followed by OR. Their main advantage is a regular structure that not only can implement large functions, but they’re easily modified. FPGAs use lookup tables to do something similar.

Comment: can/is this shared wiring be used in the current compute hardware which operates at GHz frequency?

Comment: And does this shared wiring help cram more logic per unit area, while not disturbing other factors and without introducing new problems?